# Discriminant of the characteristic equation

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory

I want to know, what is the relationship between a matrix A and the discriminant of its characteristic polynomial. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The discriminant of a polynomial can help us find repeated roots. Let $A$ have eigenvalues $\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n$. Then the discriminant of the characteristic polynomial of $A$, call it $p_A(x)$, is given by $$D(p_A(x)) = \prod_{i<j}^n (\lambda_j-\lambda_i).$$ Note of course that the roots of the characteristic polynomial are the eigenvalues of $A$.

So, any time that $D(p_A(x))$ (the discriminant) is zero, this tells us that for some $ i \neq j$ $\lambda_i = \lambda_j$. That is, we have a repeated eigenvalue of $A$

Comment: I have a doubt, the function $D(p_A(x))$ is continuous? I mean, if you define it as $$D:M^{nxn}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$$

Comment: You would need a concept of "closeness" in the ring of $n \times n$ matrices. It is certainly an interesting question. Overall, my answer does not rely at all on continuity of the discriminant. In general though, as complex numbers have uncountably many products into which they can decompose, my guess is that this is not continuous in any reasonable metric space.

Comment: Yes, but, I was thinking, $D$ is like a composition of functions, the polynomial characteristic of a matrix and the discriminant of a polynomial. both are polinomic funtions, aren't they?,it must mean something.

Comment: The discriminant is a mapping from a ring of polynomials to the complex numbers. I'm sure that we can find meaning in many things such as this.